# Choosing unit of measure system

Tags: radio-buttons, app, grouped-list, select

Our app (http://www.fitnessmealplanner.com) requires users to enter basic info about themselves such as height and weight.
Problem is that even after trying several changes to layout people still skip/miss/don't understand the button of US/Metric selection is clickable and then people who are used to metric system (US is default) fail to identify the option and have difficulty to enter values.

The question is how can one best improve the layout/ui so it will still be elegant and have a better user experience - easy to be identified and used:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been trying out different fitness apps over the last week or so, and have come across this issue on a lot of them. The very worst offenders are the ones that don't allow you to switch unit types altogether.

Some things I'm noticing with your layout:

1) The header for 'Preferred unit of measure' appears to be the header for the entire screen, and thus gets a bit lost

2)  It's not very clear that the two unit types are clickable, and since their relevance only comes into play further down the screen, it's likely to be ignored, until the user becomes confused by the unit types.

3) The unit labels (cm, kg) are pretty far from the units, aligned to right like that makes it difficult to associate with the unit.

I would propose:

Create a toggle button for Metric | Imperial and keep the alignment and treatment consistent with the rest of the form, it should be treated as another question to be answered. So you would have something like:

[image: Rough example]

Comment: Good idea, I'llcheck out how it looks consistent with the rest of the form, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove Measurement Options: "Preferred Unit of Measure" line, "US Customary" and "Metric" sections. This answer relies on either Android SDK being used, or an advanced enough App Creation Tool being used that allows a label, input box and option dropdown to appear on same line.

Use same dropdown option as used with Gender for height and weight. This will (1) reduce clutter and reading time for all users, and (2) remove any confusion but especially for non-US users as to how to change option. Use Bayesian inference, if a user changes height from ft/inches default to centimeters; ***also change*** weight from default pounds to kilograms. 95+% of users that fill in their height as centimeters will then use kilograms. By inferring the user's measurement preference, they now only have to make one click just like current setup.

The labels "Gender, Age, Height, Weight" should be in bold. Also for sake of throwing it in, for user validation. A soft grey message at start telling user to pay careful attention to input could also help.

[image: Kitten user entry warning message]

Some important extra logic:

- Only change the other measurement once on the first change made by user and if other input is empty. Eg Alice changes height to centimeters, UI automatically changes weight to kilograms; Alice enters her height but then she decides to be funny / unexpected, changes weight back to kilograms, enters her weight in pounds. Obviously, do not change height back to inches.
- Alternately, Alice decides to fill in form in reverse. She changes weight from pounds to kilograms; UI automatically changes height to centimeters, and she enters her weight. If she interacts now with the height and decides to use feet/inch, UI should not make any auto-magic Bayesian inferences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, interesting, but i do believe it is partially covered in Phoebe's answer which is also more simple and less change

Answer (score 0):

When I see imperial units or F degrees for temperature, I usually look for a switch. Because good American apps always have unit switch to metric. There is no discoverability problem for me – I just know there should be a switch somewhere.

But actually, I've already decided what units I prefer – in System Settings. Why not use it for default?